# tikz: draw arc between two specific points

Tags: positioning, tikz-styles, coordinates, arc, curve-fitting

How can I draw between two specific coordinates? Cord are (1,0) and (5,0)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % <---

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\path[name path=t] (1,0) to[out=90,in=180] (2,1) to[out=0,in=90] (3,0); % top arc
    \draw[blue] (0,0)--++(0,1);
    \draw[red] (0,1)--++(6,0);
    \draw[yellow] (6,1)--(6,0);
    \draw[green] (0,0)--(1,0);
    \draw[orange] (6,0)--++(-1,0);
    \draw[magenta] (1,0) arc
        [
            start angle=160,
            end angle=20,
            x radius=2cm,
            y radius =0.5cm
        ] ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is what you want different from what you get? (then, what do you want?)

Comment: An arc betwenn (0,1) and (5,0) coordinates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/198137/2907484 may help. If you need exactly an ellipse with the given radiuses; otherways you can just `(0,1) to [bend left] (5,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some different arcs:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yshift=0cm]  (1,0) to [bend right=45] (5,0);
\draw[yshift=2cm]  (1,0) to [bend left=45] (5,0);
\draw[yshift=4cm]  (1,0) to [out=135, in=45] (5,0);
\draw[yshift=6cm]  (1,0) to [out=135, in=45, looseness=2] (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Four different arcs]

Comment: Add an example with OP's MWE to make the answer complete.

Comment: @antshar: I can not do that, as I do not understand what OPs code has to do with the question.

Comment: Clearly, they want to connect ends of a polyline with an arc (magenta) https://imgur.com/EAGAmEl

Comment: @antshar I disagree on the word "clearly".

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,patterns,positioning} % <---
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray,pattern=dots, pattern color=gray,] (0,0)--++(0,1) 
    to (0,1)--++(12,0)
    to (12,1)--(12,0) 
    to (12,0)--(11,0)
    to (11,0) to [bend left=-15] (1,0)
    to (1,0) to (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use the answer section to ask a new question. Please delete this "answer". TikZ will rotate around `(0,0)` if nothing else is given. You can specify the point to rotate around with `rotate around={180:(6,5)}` - choose the coordinates to be above the center of your shape.